# Different results by similar functionality in c++

Tags: c++

I have the following task:

Develop a hotel reservation system to allow customers to book rooms and control demand for hotel owners. Your program should handle the following events:

- **BOOK time hotel_name client_id room_count** — Book by the client with
  ID client_id a certain number of rooms (room_count) at the hotel
  named hotel_name at the specified time (time). Time is measured in
  seconds from a certain moment.
- **CLIENTS hotel_name** — Display the count of different clients who have
  booked rooms at the hotel named hotel_name in the last 24 hours. More
  formally, the time range of interest is described as follows: let
  current_time be the time of the last BOOK event. In this query,
  consider all events with current_time - 86400 < time ⩽ current_time,
  where 86400 is the number of seconds in a day. Note that the last
  booking should be considered, and a booking exactly 24 hours prior to
  it should not be included.
- **ROOMS hotel_name** — Display the count of rooms booked in the last 24
  hours at the hotel named hotel_name.

In my first version I came up with the following approach:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

class HotelManagement {

public:

  HotelManagement() : hotel_rooms(), hotel_time(){}

  void Book (int &time, string &hotel_name, int &client_id, int &room_count){
    hotel_rooms[hotel_name].push_back(room_count);
    hotel_time[hotel_name].push_back(time);

    for (auto &pair : hotel_time){
         while(hotel_time.at(pair.first).front() <= time - 86400){
          if (!pair.second.empty()){
            hotel_time.at(pair.first).pop_front();
            hotel_rooms.at(pair.first).pop_front();
          }
      }
    }
  }

  int Clients(string &hotel_name){
    deque<int>& times = hotel_time[hotel_name]; 
    return times.size();
  }

  int Rooms(string &hotel_name){
    deque<int>& rooms = hotel_rooms[hotel_name];
    int total_room = 0;
    for(auto r:rooms){
      total_room += r;
    }
    return total_room;
  }

private:
  map<string,deque<int>> hotel_rooms;
  map<string,deque<int>> hotel_time;
};
```

In which each **Book** deleted unnecessary records from deques. It works on hidden tests, but is quite slow.

I decided to try different approach, where I shifted part of **Book** functionality to **Client** and **Room* methods:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

class HotelManagement {

public:
  HotelManagement() : current_time(-99999999),hotel_rooms(), hotel_time(){}

  void Book (int &time, string &hotel_name, int &client_id, int &room_count){
    hotel_rooms[hotel_name].push_back(room_count);
    hotel_time[hotel_name].push_back(time);
    current_time = time;
    }

  int Clients(string &hotel_name){
    deque<int>& times = hotel_time[hotel_name]; 
    deque<int>& rooms = hotel_rooms[hotel_name];

    if (times.size() == 0){
      return 0;
    }

    while(times.front() <= current_time - 86400){
      if (!times.empty()){
        times.pop_front();
        rooms.pop_front();
        }
    }
    return times.size();
  }


  int Rooms(string &hotel_name){
    deque<int>& times = hotel_time[hotel_name]; 
    deque<int>& rooms = hotel_rooms[hotel_name];
    
    if (times.size() == 0){
      return 0;
    }

    while(times.front() <= current_time - 86400){
      if (!times.empty()){
        times.pop_front();
        rooms.pop_front();
        }
    }
    
    
    int total_room = 0;
    for(auto r:rooms){
      total_room += r;
    }
    return total_room;
  }

private:
  map<string,deque<int>> hotel_rooms;
  map<string,deque<int>> hotel_time;
  int current_time;
};
```

and on one hidden test I get "wrong answer", however I thought that functionality should be the same ( basically I copy-pasted part of a Code from Book method to Client and Room methods).

I don't see what I am missing here.

Here is a shore main method and one test case (this one works fine on both methods).

```
int main() {
  ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(nullptr);

  HotelManagement hotel;

  int query_count;
  cin >> query_count;

  for (int query_id = 0; query_id < query_count; ++query_id) {
    string query_type;
    cin >> query_type;

    if (query_type == "BOOK") {
      int time, client_id, room_count;
      string hotel_name;
      cin >> time >> hotel_name >> client_id >> room_count;
      hotel.Book(time, hotel_name, client_id, room_count);
    } else if (query_type == "CLIENTS") {
      string hotel_name;
      cin >> hotel_name;
      cout << hotel.Clients(hotel_name) << "\n";
    } else if (query_type == "ROOMS") {
      string hotel_name;
      cin >> hotel_name;
      cout << hotel.Rooms(hotel_name) << "\n";
    } 
    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Test Case:**

Input:

```
11
CLIENTS Marriott
ROOMS Marriott
BOOK 10 FourSeasons 1 2
BOOK 10 Marriott 1 1
BOOK 86409 FourSeasons 2 1
CLIENTS FourSeasons
ROOMS FourSeasons
CLIENTS Marriott
BOOK 86410 Marriott 2 10
ROOMS FourSeasons
ROOMS Marriott
```

Output:

```
0
0
2
3
1
1
10
```

**EDIT:** here is an output of the second approach on the hidden test.

```
Failed case #4/17: Wrong answer

 (Time used: 0.00/1.00, preprocess time used: 0/None, memory used: 102293504/536870912.)
```

Comment: `for(auto r:rooms)` -- This should be taken by reference, not by value.  `for(auto& r:rooms)` -- By taking by value, you are making an entire copy of the pair, which contains a `std::string` that has to be constructed each time the `for` loop iterates.

Comment: *basically I copy-pasted part of a Code from Book method to Client and Room methods* -- You changed the code, regardless.  In the real-life programming world, *any* code change is tested against a test suite, no matter how small the change is.  You cannot rely "on sight" that the new functionality is the same as the old functionality, especially when you move large pieces of code around (doesn't matter if it is almost a copy/paste).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know, that I changed a code, it was a figure of speech (I am not a native english speaker), I am sorry if I was confusing. I didn't rely blindly on the changes, I tested both versions on my own test cases (one I posted in the original post) and they were identical. The only difference is in the hidden test and I don't understand why the second version failed and the first one didn't

Comment: Try putting some debug logs and run.

Comment: Try using int64_t for all time, ID and count values. Maybe the tests contain very large numbers. (Ask your professor about the limits on those.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first solution does immediate maintaining, while your second one does late-maintaining. This can lead to problems if the reservation time is around the limit of `int`.

Make 3 reservations with the following time values: 2147483647 - 86400, 2147483647, 2147483647 + 86400 + 1

Querying the rooms/clients after the 3rd booking should consider only the last reservation.

Your first approach is going to remove the first reservation during the second booking.
Your second approach is not going to remove any bookings at all.

```cpp
    int maxValue = 2147483647;
    int firstTime{maxValue - 86400};
    int secondTime{maxValue};
    int thirdTime{maxValue + 86400};

    int time;
    time = firstTime;
    std::cout << std::format("Booking time: {}", time) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::format("Reservations made before {} will be ignored\n\n", time - 86400 + 1);

    time = secondTime;
    std::cout << std::format("Booking time: {}", time) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::format("Reservations made before {} will be ignored", time - 86400 + 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::format("Does it remove the first reservation? {:s}", firstTime <= time - 86400) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    time = thirdTime;
    std::cout << std::format("Booking time: {}", time) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::format("Reservations made before {} will be ignored", time - 86400 + 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::format("Does it remove the first reservation? {:s}", firstTime <= time - 86400) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::format("Does it remove the second reservation? {:s}", secondTime <= time - 86400) << std::endl;
```

```
Booking time: 2147397247
Reservations made before 2147310848 will be ignored

Booking time: 2147483647
Reservations made before 2147397248 will be ignored
Does it remove the first reservation? true

Booking time: -2147397248
Reservations made before -2147483647 will be ignored
Does it remove the first reservation? false
Does it remove the second reservation? false
```

Since your task description says

> Time is measured in seconds from a certain moment

I would use `unsigned int` or `uint64_t` for time representation.

### Update

Forgot to mention: The above example might/might not work with your compiler. It's crucial to know that behavior of signed overflow is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

This part

```cpp
    while(times.front() <= current_time - 86400){
      if (!times.empty()){
        times.pop_front();
        rooms.pop_front();
        }
    }
```

may refer invalid `times.front()` if the deque `times` becomes empty at `times.pop_front();`.

It should be:

```cpp
    while(!times.empty() && times.front() <= current_time - 86400){
      times.pop_front();
      rooms.pop_front();
    }
```

Comment: It's a good advice, thank you! But still I am getting the wrong answer on the test (see EDIT section above). 

But to me it's strange, that one approach passes test, but second approach doesn't. I don't understand why.

Comment: @DaniilYefimov The difference in the algorithm can make difference when `BOOK` queries with smaller `time` can appear after ones with larger `time`. Can this situration occur?

Comment: No, it cannot. Deques are sorted